# using flash media server with moodle whiteboard

Tags: php, moodle, whiteboard

I am trying to use flash media server with moodle [Course Management System] to use it the steps tells me to add this line of code :

```
$CFG->fms = 'YourFmsLink';
```

as following this link :

http://moodlemodules.netcourse.org/2007/11/17/whiteboard/

well I installed my whiteboard module and it works but after I draw a shape on whiteboard write on the whitebord my writings will disappear

what is the problem ,Thanks in advance

Comment: great ,wold you please post this question there and send me the link

Comment: It's at a proposal stage. You can click on follow and add your question as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well there is another solution for your problem A nice open source web conferencing system called

> BigBlueButton

BigBlueButton have Module for Moodle 
videos to show how the activity modules work
http://blindsidenetworks.com/video/moodle19/index.html

this video to show how to use whiteboard

http://bigbluebutton.org/sites/all/videos/whiteboard/index.html

hope it's useful

Comment: could you explain i a short description what is the different ? :)

Comment: the difference is that the whiteboard module just to create whiteboard

Comment: thanks reana and maha :)  ,I found the answer I am going to use it as it is